# changing datagrid's date time string formatting within autoGenColumnsArray

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, string-formatting

My Datagrid (dg) has several columns, one of which (the right-most column) contain dates. The rest of the columns do not contain dates. I want strings in the dates column shown to the user as DD/MM/YYYY (without the time.) However, once the grid is bound and the page loads, it shows up as DD/MM/YYYY 12:00 AM.

From searching, I thought I would try to do something like this:

```
foreach (DataControlField field in dg.Columns)
    {
        if (field is BoundField)
        {
            BoundField boundField = field as BoundField;
            boundField.DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}";
            boundField.HtmlEncode = false;             
        }
    }
```

However, the data is not in dg.Columns, it is actually in dg.autoGenColumnsArray[0-10], with 10 being the column index with the dates that I want to format. What do I do in order to format this column?

EDIT: I am using a panel:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="labelSqlDefaults">
```

also, in my code-behind (where dg is my datagrid):

```
dg.DataBind();
this.labelSqlDefaults.Controls.Add(dg);
```

Answer (score 0):

format it propery as it bounds on your aspx end

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="false" >
```

Comment: When I try this, there is a warning: Element 'BoundField' is not a known element. I am using a panel: `<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="labelSqlDefaults">` and in my code-behind I have `this.labelSqlDefaults.Controls.Add(dg);`

Comment: are you doing on bound or as itemtemplete